# installing Acronis True Image 2020

Tags: backup

I am trying to install a trial version of Acronis True Image. The website downloaded an exe file into my downloads dir. My choice was PC or MAC. I chose PC.  I assumed that I could double left click on it and it would install like in Windows. It won't and I can't get into their support queue without registering the products. Ugh! Am I trying to install a Windows version on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: It will be easer to find Mac or Win machine around. Acronis will not work [with Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6834). What is your final idea? Ubuntu have other native utilities for backups, so you do not need Acronis.

Comment: Yes and it probably won't work.  Would see this link for software like Acronis that works on Ubuntu or google ubuntu backup.  https://alternativeto.net/   Usually want a .deb file for ubuntu

Comment: I use back in time on my development laptop just in case I screw something up while developing. But I am concerned with my laptop being stolen or the hard drive dying. I have a lot of time invested in the code in that machine. It also took a long time to get all of the configuration correct. As a backup (no pun intended) I'd like to clone the drive say once a month and upload to web storage, just to make sure that I can at least get back somewhat from a theft without a total loss.

Comment: Use Clonezilla, it's free and works great. You just have to deal with the 1980s style interface. https://clonezilla.org/

Comment: Thanks guys. clonezilla sounds great. Are there reasonable online storage solutions that work well with it?

Comment: I have been looking through clonezilla and it seems like a pretty large undertaking. I am pretty busy trying to get my app developed and can't afford to get sidetracked. I need something commercial, not a roll your own. But I'd really like a vendor who offers the entire package (backup, image, web storage). Anyone know who does the entire package?

Comment: Well I saw a message from someone who had their entire laptop stolen. It got me worried. I use Back In Time but it backs up to my own hard drive. I need to backup to a cloud drive just in case. That plus I have a entire laptop full of configurations. So for that reason I was thinking clonezilla is a good idea, but how often can you create a clone-able image?